# platform independent sqlite data access layer for ipad / iphone / android / samsung bada

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, sqlite, mobile

we have an app which is available for ipad, iphone, android as well as samsung bada. since all of these platforms support sqlite, this app makes extensive use of sqlite for saving and reading data.

we now face quite a lot of issues whenever we need to update our app, that is punch in the same data access code across 4 different apps. we might also be looking to publish this app for windows mobile at a future date

i was wondering if there is a way to atleast have a completely independent library to manage our data access part so that we can just code and update this library once and simply use it across all 4 platforms

it would be awesome to achieve that and it would save us plenty of hours of coding and debugging and testing

Comment: Could try Appcelerator Titanium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because what you are asking for is essentially a SQL client layer sitting on top of SQLite similar to Oracle's SQL Client for Linux, Windows and so on that sits on top of the Oracle DB server that a developer could code to.  This SQL client layer would have to define a standard interface (think JDBC or ODBC) and be implemented in Java (Android), C#, VB, and F# (Windows Mobile 7), and Objective-C (iOS).

Having said that, do I expect to see such a chunk of software developing over time, considering that SQLite does seem to be the defacto standard on handsets?  Yes, I would expect to see something pop up on Git somewhere in the future that does something like that.